# Difference Between Figure Axis and Sub Plot Axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if someone could help with understanding sub plots.

The term axis is often used with figure windows and subplots and i wanted to understand whether there was a technical difference between axis of a subplot and axis of a figure window.

If i have a 2 x 2 figure allowing me 4 subplots then each subplot will have its own X*Y axis but what does it mean for the figure window to have an axes?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

> The term **axis** is often used with figure windows and subplots

A figure contains one or more Axes. An Axes contains an x and y Axis among other things.
[Anatomy of a figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure)

> what does it mean for the figure window to have an axes

From the [Introductory Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#axes)

> Axes
> This is what you think of as 'a plot', it is the region of the image with the data space.  A given figure can contain many Axes, but a given Axes object can only be in one Figure. The Axes contains two (or three in the case of 3D) Axis objects (be aware of the difference between **Axes** and **Axis**)...

A figure has one or multiple Axes. The Axes are the same type whether they are subplot Axes or the Axes of a Figure with no subplots.

Figure with multiple Axes.

```
>>> import matplotlib as mpl
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

>>> fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
>>> fig
<Figure size 640x480 with 4 Axes>
>>> ax
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A6AC707F0>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A79F52A60>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A7E960A90>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A7E98C040>]],
      dtype=object)
>>> fig.axes
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A6AC707F0>, <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A79F52A60>, <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A7E960A90>, <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A7E98C040>]
>>>
```

Figure with one Axes.

```
>>> fig,ax = plt.subplots()
>>> ax
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A678746A0>
>>> fig.axes
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A678746A0>]
>>>
>>> isinstance(fig.axes[0],mpl.axes.Axes)
True
```

Figure with one Axes.  Make the *plot* with `pyplot` then get the current Figure and Axes.

```
>>> lines = plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000025A67857C10>]
>>> fig = plt.gcf()
>>> fig.axes
[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A678746A0>]
>>> plt.gca()
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000025A678746A0>
>>>
```

The **Axes** has an x and y **Axis**.

```
>>> ax = plt.gca()
>>> ax.xaxis
<matplotlib.axis.XAxis object at 0x0000025A67874AF0>
>>> ax.yaxis
<matplotlib.axis.YAxis object at 0x0000025A67861370>
>>>
>>> isinstance(ax.xaxis,mpl.axis.Axis)
True
```

---

[Artist tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html) is worth reading (as well as the other tutorials).